# How to throttle Futures with one-second delay with Akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have list of URIs, each of which I want to request with a one-second delay in between. How can I do that?

```
val uris: List[String] = List()
// How to make these URIs resolve 1 second apart?
val responses: List[Future[Response]] = uris.map(httpRequest(_))
```

Comment: This looks like Java code, not Scala... you declare variables with `val` or `var` in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an Akka Streams `Source` from the list of URIs, then [`throttle`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html#throttle) the conversion of each URI to a `Future[Response]`:

```
def httpRequest(uri: String): Future[Response] = ???

val uris: List[String] = ???

val responses: Future[Seq[Response]] =
  Source(uris)
    .throttle(1, 1 second)
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(httpRequest)
    .runWith(Sink.seq[Response])
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perahps:

```
  @tailrec
  def withDelay(
    uris: Seq[String], 
    delay: Duration = 1 second, 
    result: List[Future[Response]] = Nil,
  ): Seq[Future[Response]] = uris match {
     case Seq() => result.reversed
     case (head, tail@_*) => 
        val v = result.headOption.getOrElse(Future.successful(null))
          .flatMap { _ => 
            akka.pattern.after(delay, context.system.scheduler)(httpRequest(head))
          }
        withDelay(tail, delay, v :: result)
   }
```

this has a delay before the first execution as well, but I hope, it's clear enough how to get rid of it if necessary ...
Another caveat is that this assumes that all futures succeed. As soon as one fails, all subsequent processing is aborted. 
If you need a different behavior, you may want to replace the `.flatMap` with `.transform` or add a `.recover` etc.

You can also write the same with `.foldLeft` if preferred:

```
  uris.foldLeft(List.empty[Future[Response]]) { case (results, next) => 
    results.headOption.getOrElse(Future.successful(null))
      .flatMap { _ => 
        akka.pattern.after(delay, context.system.scheduler)(httpRequest(next))
      } :: results
  }.reversed
```

Comment: doesn't this delay every future by 1 second and not one after the other? like first is delayed 1 sec, second is delayed 2 seconds, third is delayed 3 seconds

Comment: It adds a 1 second delay before executing each future. So, effectively, yes, total of N seconds delay for the Nth execution. Isn't it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

akka streams has it [out of the box with the `throttle` function](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html) (taking into account that you are using akka-http and added tag for akka streams)